# Citus: Can I view sharded tables of each node on master node?

Tags: postgresql, distributed-database, citus

I am managing my PostgreSQL cluster in [docker-compose](https://github.com/citusdata/docker#docker-compose) and I have connected to master(coordinator) node via external client. For a given table(for example `companies`) and a given node number(for example worker 2 or other identifier), can I view sharded tables(for example `companies_000005}`,`companies_0000010}` and their rows on worker 2) in master node without directly connecting to the individual node?

Answer (score 0):

To see some information about the shards (such as shard sizes or which node the shard is on), you can use the following query with Citus 10 and later:

```
SELECT * FROM citus_shards;
```

Also, accessing the shards directly is not a suggested pattern, and it prevents certain checks/enforcements that Citus does around distributed locking and correctness etc. With that in mind, why do you need to access the shards directly?